# What happens when I plug charger to itelf?

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-current, electrical-resistance, batteries, short-circuits

I have an amusing experiment with my smart phone charger. That is, after charging it fully, I connect its input and output toghether, and get surprise result. 
Could you see in my youtube clip and give your explanation here
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-XtVLUv4pgg

Comment: Why exactly do you think the result is surprising? Did you expect it to charge itself?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it isn't  question about physics. You could try the [Electrical Engineering Stack Exchange](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: 1. Please make your question self-contained. Currently, one has to watch a YouTube video to understand what "surprise result" you are talking about. 2. Please explain *what* is surprising about the result.

Comment: What is the "surprise result"? What do you want us to explain?

Answer (score 1):

The battery is driving current through a resistive (charging) circuit and so heat is being generated at the expense of the chemical energy stored in the battery.  Eventually that chemical energy runs out.